# Ruby on rails with AJAX - Very simply calculator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This is my first ruby on rails application. I want to make a very simple calculator, but it doesn't calculate. I want to calculate on the server site. Code below

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'calculators/new'
  get 'calculators/create'
  resources :calculators

  root to: 'calculators#new'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

app\views\calculators\create.html.erb

```
document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = <%= @sum %>
```

app\views\calculators\new.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag calculators_path, :method => :post, :remote => true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :data, nil, :onkeyup => "this.form.sub.click()" %> = <span id="sum"></span>
  <%= submit_tag "ok", :name => "sub"%>
<% end %>
```

app\controllers\calculators_controller.rb

```
class CalculatorsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @sum = eval(params[:data])
  end
end
```

The following errors appear in the logs:

BROWSER

```
SyntaxError in CalculatorsController#create

(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input

Rails.root: /home/crancode/Desktop/studia/zad3_v3

Application Trace
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
app/controllers/calculators_controller.rb:3:in `eval'
app/controllers/calculators_controller.rb:3:in `create'

Framework Trace
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (6.1.1) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (6.1.1) lib/action_text/engine.rb:55:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
actionview (6.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
activerecord (6.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (6.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:98:in `call'
rack-mini-profiler (2.3.1) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:373:in `call'
webpacker (5.2.1) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:247:in `call'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:337:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/server.rb:432:in `process_client'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'

Full Trace
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
app/controllers/calculators_controller.rb:3:in `eval'
app/controllers/calculators_controller.rb:3:in `create'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (6.1.1) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (6.1.1) lib/action_text/engine.rb:55:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
actionview (6.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
activerecord (6.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (6.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:98:in `call'
rack-mini-profiler (2.3.1) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:373:in `call'
webpacker (5.2.1) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:247:in `call'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:337:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/server.rb:432:in `process_client'
puma (5.2.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'



Request parameters
{"data"=>"2+",
 "sub"=>"ok"}

Session dump
_csrf_token: "_HyGon2ni-rzV2v9haqyAKOPGTk52oSq7TpklxT1dgQ="
session_id: "de90be13838026449531cd93bdf17f15"

Env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.2"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.5"
HTTP_ORIGIN: "http://localhost:3000"
HTTP_VERSION: "HTTP/1.1"
HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN: "Eng2-4pM0KCUfSpu_-pydplFUCbeurmEXlxnqVSQVNVNvw77fkYwl2-D28WD053sqIgavIUb7n8J8BLoUO-q9w"
ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME: ""
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"

Response headers
None
```

SERVER

```
Started POST "/calculators" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-30 15:23:17 +0100
Processing by CalculatorsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"data"=>"2+", "sub"=>"ok"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (Allocations: 613)


  
SyntaxError ((eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input):
  
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
app/controllers/calculators_controller.rb:3:in `eval'
app/controllers/calculators_controller.rb:3:in `create'
Started POST "/calculators" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-30 15:23:18 +0100
Processing by CalculatorsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"data"=>"2+2", "sub"=>"ok"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering calculators/create.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered calculators/create.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 39)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 8.5ms | Allocations: 3015)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 9.3ms | Allocations: 3449)
```

Thanks

Comment: But why? I get if you want to learn ajax, but it's just a ridiculously overcomplicated Ruby Goldberg solution to a problem that can handled in the client with javascript. You don't need the server to do simple calculations.

Comment: I know Ruby is an overkill for this task but is the content of the assignment I have to complete for my studies. Doing this task in pure js or java would not be a problem for me.

Comment: what do you see in your rails server logs? is it hitting the right action with the right format? what do you see in your browser's log? is it doing the right request? is it getting the right response? (check the Networks tab) do you have any js error?

Comment: I have now added logs to the post

Answer (score 0):

I changed filename from create.html.erb to create.js.erb and it works. Thanks for tips.